# awk split parameter by char

Tags: text-processing, awk

file is:

```
BASH.NIR
SH.ABI
```

I want the awk script to show:

```
User is NIR, SHELL is BASH
User is ABI, SHELL is SH
```

I don't know how to split a parameter by char.
The idea is:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print "User is " afterDot($1) ", SHELL is " beforeDot($1)}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string functions in `awk`.

```
$ (echo BASH.NIR; echo SH.ABI FOOBAR) | awk '{p=index($1,".");print "User is", substr($1,p+1) ", SHELL IS", substr($1,0,p-1)}'
User is NIR, SHELL IS BASH
User is ABI, SHELL IS SH
```

The `index` function returns the position of the character to be found (in this case a dot) and `substr` will return a substring.  We use `p+1` and `p-1` to not include the dot.

For more information look in the "String Functions" section of the `awk` manpage.

Answer (score 28):

You can just use `.` as the field separator:

```
awk -F. '{ print "User is " $2 ", SHELL is " $1 }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as I hoped but it got the job done :

```
echo "BASH.NIR\nSH.ABI" \
 \
 | mawk 'sub( /$/,  ", SHELL is " ($!_=$!_))+\
         sub(/^[^ ]* /,"User is ")' FS='[.]'

User is NIR, SHELL is BASH
User is ABI, SHELL is SH
```

Only can confirm it works for `gawk`, `mawk-1`, and `mawk-2`.
Can't get `nawk` onboard.